# Adding a shape to a rectangle div

Tags: html, css

I have a Rectangle div (its a heading to a column) and I want to put a ribbon/bookmark type of shape which is on the rectangle but also above it.

The jsfiddle I have so far is http://jsfiddle.net/Conye9980/zujLrs3d/3/

```css
.triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #555;
    align:right;
}
.square {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #555;
    align:right;
}
.rect {
    margin: 20px;
    width:200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Example of what I want it to look like is here:

[image]

Comment: If you search for CSS Ribbon you will find many examples here and other resources.

Comment: Something that you might want to try doesn't require much css but rather making a SVG [viewbox][1] which is a predefined space you create which is dynamic and flexible which when done can be set to the background image of the coulomb heading.


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paulie_D said you will find tons of examples searching for ribbon in CSS. Nevertheless, to achieve what you want I strongly recommend to take a look to SVG, it will be much more maleable and easy to achieve.

But, to go in the way you started, take a look to this fiddle, I took yours as a base and added some more code, it looks like what you want to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/rdarioduarte/b0sthgL6/

```css
.rect {
  margin: 20px;
  width:200px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5261AC;
  position: relative;
}
.bookmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 10px;
}
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #50C9B5;
}
.triangle-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #50C9B5;
}
.bookmark-back {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #38A1A4;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">
  <div class="bookmark">
    <div class="square"></div>
 <div class="triangle-down"></div>
 <div class="bookmark-back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, interesting way to look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Is that good enough for you? I wrapped to two part of the "ribbon" in one `div`, and gave it `position: absolute` and `top & right` positioning.

```css
   .triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #555;
    align:right;
}
.square {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #555;
    align:right;
}

.rect {
    margin: 20px;
    width:200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position:relative;
}

#ribbon {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect">
  <div id="ribbon">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <div class="triangle-down"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change Your css to the following:

```
    .triangle-down {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 25px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #555;
    align:right;
    }

    .square {
    top: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #555;
    position: absolute;
    align:right;
    }

    .rect {
    margin: 20px;
    width:200px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: yellow;
```

Basically, setting the position to absolute should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect. Much appreciated.